# Can I ask a question about dual citizenship?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have a question about a specific situation concerning the possibility of acquiring dual citizenship between Canada and Norway. I've considered Law SE, but I'm unsure whether such a question would constitute legal advice. I also feel that such a question would be better asked here. My question would be along the lines of whether acquiring a second citizenship would require me to renounce my original citizenship, haven been given certain circumstances for possible exemptions to renouncing the original citizenship.

Can I ask such a question here?

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like a perfect fit to me.

Answer (score 5):

It's not just a perfect fit, we already have a few questions similar to yours, for example:

- [Will I forfeit my French citizenship when taking on US citizenship?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/6083/dual-citizenship-france-and-usa)
- [What happens when Chinese acquire foreign citizenship?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/4455/what-happens-when-chinese-acquire-foreign-citizenship)
- [Renunciation of original nationality in the process of becoming a Dutch citizen](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/6547/renunciation-of-original-nationality-in-the-process-of-becoming-a-dutch-citizen)

There is also a tag called [dual-citizenship](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dual-citizenship)